# Aggregate sum from diff columns using conditions. PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

The task is to get know how much money player earned during the year.
So I want to write a select where by the known `player_id` I will aggregate his total win like.

[image: tournament scheme]

`FIRST_PLAYER_ID` is an id of player who got the first place and FIRST_PRICE accordingly.

What I need:

```
player_id | total_prize_sum_over_all_tournaments_played_by_him
```

Code i tried so far:

```
SELECT PLAYER.SUNAME, TOURNAMENT.NAME FROM PLAYER
JOIN TOURNAMENT
ON PLAYER.ID = TOURNAMENT.FIRST_PLAYER_ID
OR PLAYER.ID = TOURNAMENT.SECOND_PLAYER_ID
OR PLAYER.ID = TOURNAMENT.THIRD_PLAYER_ID
ORDER BY PLAYER.BIRTH_DATE
```

Also, please help me to name this question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sql statement aggregates the prize money won by each player. The idea is to aggregate by each rank individually, summing up the results for each player afterwards.

```
    SELECT pt.p_id
         , SUM(pt.tl)
      FROM (
                SELECT p.p_id
                     , sum(t.first_prize)   tl
                  FROM player p
                  JOIN tournament t on ( t.first_player_id    = p.p_id )
              GROUP BY p.p_id
             UNION ALL
                SELECT p.p_id
                     , sum(t.second_prize)  tl
                  FROM player p
                  JOIN tournament t on ( t.second_player_id    = p.p_id )
              GROUP BY p.p_id
             UNION ALL
                SELECT p.p_id
                     , sum(t.third_prize)   tl
                  FROM player p
                  JOIN tournament t on ( t.third_player_id    = p.p_id )
              GROUP BY p.p_id
            ) pt      
   GROUP BY pt.p_id
          ;
```

[This sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6e944/5) is a full-fledged example (with restricted table definitons).

Comment: At the time of writing, sql fiddle's oracle db seems to be unable to process scripts, therefore sqlite has been chosen as the platform. however, i have verified the solution works on a 11g2 db,